# XPath 1.0 condition: select a if b has value of true

Tags: xml, xpath-1.0

I have this simple xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<json encoding="UTF-8" has-bom="false" html-processing-enabled="true" replaceEntities="true" version="1.0">
    <map>
        <element isString="1" text="key">GREETING_ID</element>
        <element isString="1" text="value">hello</element>
        <element isString="1" text="comment">this is a greeting</element>
        <element isString="0" text="maxLength">5</element>
        <element isString="0" text="needsTranslation">true</element>
    </map>
    <map>
        <element isString="1" text="key">FAREWELL_ID</element>
        <element isString="1" text="value">bye</element>
        <element isString="1" text="comment">this is a farewell</element>
        <element isString="0" text="maxLength">10</element>
        <element isString="0" text="needsTranslation">false</element>
    </map>
</json>
```

I would like to select Element node with attribute text="value" but only if in the same Map node element with attribute text="needsTranslation" has text equal to "true". I just started my journey with XPath and I'm clueless on where to even begin.

Comment: This is template for file with translatable content. In this example I would like to select "hello" for translation but not "bye" and Element node with "needsTranslation" holds boolean stating if this should go for translation or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that (I've tested it with your XML and it return `hello`) :

```
//map[element[@text="needsTranslation" and text()="true"]]/element[@text="value"]
```

This `//map[element[@text="needsTranslation" and text()="true"]]` select a

> Map node element with attribute text="needsTranslation" has text equal to "true"

and then `/element[@text="value"]` select the

> Element node with attribute text="value"

Comment: Thank you! That wokred perfectly :D +1